What's the difference between setting up bridge VLAN with `bridge` command and /etc/network/interfaces
On Debian, I noticed I can set up bridge VLANs in /etc/network/interfaces with bridge-tools installed:
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports enp2s0 enp3s0 enp4s0 enp5s0 enp7s0
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto br0.2
iface br0.2 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  vlan_raw_device br0

I just learned the other way to do this is via bridge command. What's the difference between them? Since the first way of setting up VLAN is not mentioned a lot, are there problems with it?

Typically you'd use commands like bridge directly from a shell only when you are testing. For persistent / automatic configuration upon boot, you use some sort of network manager (or at least have the commands in some scripts that would be executed on boot).

/etc/network/interfaces is just a configuration file (and a series of scripts which call proper programs to set up interfaces). You have also systemd-networkd: it is just an interface to kernel, and for kernel most things will be identical (but check if/how each program setup names, links, routes, addresses. If the results it is the same (check with ip the methods tou used doesn't matter). (PS: but configuration files are persistent at next boot)
